# Different 404 error page on web browser

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-chrome, web, browser

This site has a custom 404 error page secondhanddivas.com/testx (CodeIgniter error_404) But when I try to visit, it is just "Uh-oh" 404 message. In all web browser that I use. I tried visiting it on different machine(friend's laptop) and the custom 404 page is working.

Any ideas? Please help.

Comment: include code from igniter.  Also specify your http server

Comment: @Rafael I'm not sure if this is CI problem. Cause when I tried visiting a broken link using different laptop - the error 404 pages works with no problem. I'm wondering why using my own laptop it is shows "Uh-oh" message. Is it something web browser setting, or anything?

Comment: may be your browser attacked by virus

Comment: Hi @ShaifulIslam I have already update my antivirus. And even re-install my web browsers (Chrome and MF). I'm out of solutions.

Comment: What webserver do you use? You could use the errors logs with debug mode if you havent any idea.

Comment: Thanks everyone.
I solved it. I was looking at what programs I had installed and I say this Rocket Toolbar thing..I uninstalled it and bam.. it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I solved it. I was looking at what programs I had installed and I say this Rocket Toolbar/Rocket Tab thing... I uninstalled it and bam... it works.